# Increasing numerator o decreasing denominator?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Which fraction is bigger? How can i demonstrate it?

$$\frac{a+1}{b}$$ or $$\frac{a}{b-1}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $1<b<a+1$ then
\begin{eqnarray*}
ab+b-a-1 < ab \\
(a+1)(b-1) < ab \\
\frac{a+1}{b} < \frac{a}{b-1}. 
\end{eqnarray*}
Similarly if $b>a+1>0$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{a+1}{b} > \frac{a}{b-1}. 
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 0):

You can't tell.

If $\frac ab=\frac {0.1}{0.1}$ you have $\frac {a+1}b=\frac {1.1}{0.1}=11$ while $\frac a{b-1}=\frac {0.1}{-0.9}=-9$

If $\frac ab= \frac {10}{1.1}$ you have $\frac {a+1}b=\frac {11}{1.1}=10$ while $\frac a{b-1}=\frac {11}{0.1}=110$

Basically the $\pm 1$ will make a larger change in the smaller of $a,b$ in magnitude, with the bias that $b$ moves toward $0$ assuming it is positive.